# Android TabLayOut is not picking up colorPrimary

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Android tab layout background color is white when it should be trasparent.

[image]

It won't pick up the colorPrimary in the below code:

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                 android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" // Should pick up transparent 
                 here?
                 android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                 android:backgroundTint="#5C328A"
                 app:tabTextColor="@color/button_material_light"
                 app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
                 app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                 app:tabGravity="fill"
                 app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

colors.xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <resources>
               <color name="launcher_background">#FFFFFF</color>
               <color name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</color>
               <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E3E31E</color>
               <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
            </resources>
```

Xaml tabs on page:

```
                    <Grid
                    BackgroundColor="black"
                    ColumnSpacing="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    RowSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  //Closing tags below
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        global::Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
    }
```

I've gone through a number of stack overflow questions regarding tab layout and i can't find any difference in my code compared to the accepted solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use tabBackground

```
app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Comment: This still doesn't pick it up unfortunately. Am I missing some configuration file/ method?

Comment: Remove your theme and background as well... May be imapct